# running an analytic cloud functions locally and storing analytic event into a firestore collection?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I have a question regarding running an analytic cloud function and function is quite simple whenever any signup happens then it triggers and that event is stored in a collection I am using firebase emulators:start --only functions to run the function and when I am running the function normal function runs fine and not the analytic functions here is my code?
and I also want to know is this the correct way to store into firestore collection?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const serviceAccountKey = require('./keyv2.json')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKey),
});
const db = admin.firestore()
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
 console.log('hello')
});

exports.eventStore = functions.analytics.event('sign_up').onLog(async event => {
    console.log('hello')
    console.log(event)
    const user = event.user
    await db.collection('EventLogs').add(user)
    console.log('eventLog is added in the EventLogs collection')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics for Firebase events are not currently implemented by the Firebase emulators. See the Firebase documentation on the emulator suite, specifically the section [which Firebase features and platforms are supported?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite?hl=en#which_firebase_features_and_platforms_are_supported)

The code for your Analytics-triggered functions looks ok'ish, but you'll want to:

1. Make sure your code **returns** something to the Cloud Functions environment, so that it knows when your code is done. A simple `return true` at the end of the function is good enough in this case.
2. I'm not entirely sure if `event.user` can be serialized to JSON, so it might be worth wrapping it in `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))`.

Comment: because when i am trying to use your 2nd point it gives an error 
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document
code structure like this
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
    await db.collection('EventLogs').add(user)

Comment: That is interesting, because it seems like there might be some data in the `user` object that can't be serialized to JSON. You might want to first see if: 1) `user` actually has a value, 2) you can write some simple properties of `user` instead of the full object, for example just `user.firstOpenTime`.